# Merge array in the included file

Tags: php

i have 2 PHP files, config.php and confignw.php as follows,

### config.php

```
$html = array(
    [update_item_in_store] => Array
        (
            [header] => default_header.php
            [body] => update_item_in_store.php
            [footer] => default_footer.php
        )

    [user_followed] => Array
        (
            [header] => default_header.php
            [body] => user_followed.php
            [footer] => default_footer.php
        )

    [updated_account_settings] => Array
        (
            [header] => default_header.php
            [body] => updated_account_settings.php
            [footer] => default_footer.php
        )
);

$cml = array
(
    "default_header",
    "default_body",
    "default_footer"
);
```

### confignw.php

```
$html = array(
    [add_item_in_store] => Array
        (
            [header] => default_header.php
            [body] => add_item_in_store.php
            [footer] => default_footer.php
        )

    [user_followed] => Array
        (
            [header] => default_header.php
            [body] => user_followed_new.php
            [footer] => default_footer.php
        )
);

$cml = array
(
    "default_skeleton"
);
```

And both the files are included in a file called common.php,

And the result should come as merging of both as follows,

### Expected Result:

```
$html = array(
    [update_item_in_store] => Array
        (
            [header] => default_header.php
            [body] => update_item_in_store.php
            [footer] => default_footer.php
        )

    [user_followed] => Array
        (
            [header] => default_header.php
            [body] => user_followed_new.php
            [footer] => default_footer.php
        )

    [updated_account_settings] => Array
        (
            [header] => default_header.php
            [body] => updated_account_settings.php
            [footer] => default_footer.php
        )
    [add_item_in_store] => Array
        (
            [header] => default_header.php
            [body] => add_item_in_store.php
            [footer] => default_footer.php
        )
);

$cml = array
(
    "default_header",
    "default_body",
    "default_footer",
            "default_skeleton"
);
```

Look at the value added in both arrays from the array in the file `confignw.php` and note that $html[user_followed][body] is changed. But what is happening is, only the second files' values are coming. So how to achieve this expected result? Any ideas or suggestion are welcome...

Comment: If you need to merge arrays, a logical place to start would be [`array_merge`](http://us.php.net/array-merge) or [`array_merge_recursive`](http://us.php.net/array-merge-recursive). Consider changing the structure so that the included files *return* this array instead of assigning it, then assign the result of `include` to a variable in common.php - makes it easier to capture contents of both arrays and work with them.

Comment: @deceze: I tried inluding both in same file and expected to o/p the `Expected output`. That is due to if we have $arr['a'] = 1, $arr['b'] = 2, then the $arr will be array(a => 1, b => 2). And if we have it as, $arr['a'] = 1, $arr['b'] = 2 and again $arr['a'] = 5. Then the $arr will be (a => 5, b => 2). So when these things are happening when they are in the same file, why it is not happening when they are in different files(using include)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP won't magically merge the arrays. It encounters two assignments to the same variable. In `config.php` you assign some data to `$html` variable. When the file is included, the data  is assigned to the variable. Then, when `confignw.php` is included, PHP assigns the same `$html` variable *another* data. There's no merging, because there should not be any.

```
$a = array('a');
$a = array('b');
print_r($a); // prints array('b');
```

This code demonstrates what you are doing. If you want to merge the arrays, you need to tell PHP about it. For example, in `confignw.php` you could write:

```
if (!isset($html)) {
    $html = array();
}
$html = array_merge($html, array(
    'add_item_in_store' => Array
        (
            'header' => 'default_header.php',
            'body' => 'add_item_in_store.php',
            'footer' => 'default_footer.php'
        ),

    'user_followed' => Array
        (
            'header' => 'default_header.php',
            'body' => 'user_followed_new.php',
            'footer' => 'default_footer.php'
        )
));
```

If the above code doesn't do what you want, look into [array_merge_recursive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) function.

Answer (score 1):

since you're including code with variables of the same names I suppose the latter will "overwrite" the first one. Kinda like putting sheets of paper on top of another -- you'll only see the one on top.

If you want to merge these array, you'll need to assign them to variables of different names, and then use array_merge_recursive, as DCoder suggested. You might also check out array_replace_recursive function -- it should work as you wanted. Check [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php)